# Ratchet PHP Library Not Sending Response

Tags: php, websocket, chat, message, ratchet

I'm building a simple chat application using Ratchet PHP Libray, And when a user enters a message it is stored in the database then displayed .However,the user cannot receive supposedly sent messages by other users,here is the relevant part of code:

server.php ( Important function is onMessage that is responsibel for receving and sending messages back to user ) :

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;
    protected $userConnections;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->userConnections = [];
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        list($recipient_id, $message) = explode(':', $msg, 2);

        if (isset($this->userConnections[$recipient_id])) {
            echo "Received message for User ID {$recipient_id}: {$message}\n";

            $recipientConn = $this->userConnections[$recipient_id];
            $recipientConn->send($message);
        }
        
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";

        $userId = array_search($conn, $this->userConnections);
        if ($userId !== false) {
            unset($this->userConnections[$userId]);
        }
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
chat.php:
```

```
  <?php
include("connect.php");
include("auth_check.php");

$crpyted_userId = @$_GET['user_id'];
$crypted_recipient_id = @$_GET['recipient_id'];
$recipient_id = base64_decode($crypted_recipient_id);

if ( empty($recipient_id)) {
    echo("Could not validate your request. Recipient id empty");
} else {

        ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="chatroom.css">
                <title>Chat Room</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="chat-container" id="chat">
                    
                    <div class="input-container">
                        
                        <textarea type="text" id="messageInput" oninput="validateMessage()" placeholder="Type your message..." maxlength="600"></textarea>
                        <button id="send" onclick="sendMessage()"><img id="message_icon" src="uploads/message.png"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                    function validateMessage() {
                        var sendButton = document.getElementById('send');
                        var message = document.getElementById('messageInput').value.trim();
                        var isValid = message.length > 0 && message.length <= 600;
                        sendButton.disabled = !isValid;
                        return isValid;
                    }
                    
                    validateMessage();

                    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
                    const chatContainer = document.getElementById('chat');
                    chatContainer.scrollTop = 0;

                    function updateScroll() {
                        chatContainer.scrollTop = chatContainer.scrollHeight;
                    }

                    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
                        console.log("testing:");
                        chatContainer.innerHTML += '<div class="message recipient"><div class="message-content"><p>' + event.data + '</p></div></div>';
                        updateScroll();

                    };

                    function sendMessage() {
                        if (validateMessage()) {
                            const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInput');
                            const message = messageInput.value;

                            var messageData = new FormData();
                            messageData.append('message', message);
                            messageData.append('messages', 'one');
                           
                            messageData.append('recipient_id', <?php echo $recipient_id ?>);
                            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.open('POST', 'messageHandling.php', true);

                            xhr.onload = function () {
                                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                                    const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                                    const message = jsonResponse.message;
                                    //important when cannot process json response
                                    socket.send(<?php echo json_encode($recipient_id); ?> + ':' + message);
                                    chatContainer.innerHTML += '<div class="message sender"><div class="message-content"><p>' + message + '</p></div></div>';
                                    updateScroll();
                                }
                            };

                            xhr.send(messageData);
                        }
                    }
               
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        var messageData = new FormData();
                        messageData.append('recipient_id', <?php echo $recipient_id?>);
                        messageData.append('messages', 'all');  // Include 'messages' in FormData

                        xhr.open('POST','messageHandling.php', true);
                        xhr.onload = function(){
                            if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
                                var messages = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                                socket.onopen = function(){
                                    for (const msg of messages) {
                                        socket.send(<?php echo json_encode($recipient_id); ?> + ':' + msg);
                                        chatContainer.innerHTML += '<div class="message sender"><div class="message-content"><p>' + msg + '</p></div></div>';
                                        updateScroll();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        xhr.send(messageData);
                    });
                </script>
            </body>
            </html>
            <?php
        }
    

?>
```

Comment: Please post all the HTML code (not just the JS socket.onmessage part)

Comment: @KenLee,I've provided it.Please check it.

Comment: @KenLee,any ideas ?